# Best way to add a custom domain to lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, serverless-application-model

I am trying to create a lambda function using SAM, however I can't work out how to add a custom domain to it. Do I need to add a whole ApiGateway to my CloudFormation template just to change the domain or is there is an easier way?

My domain is in Route53 and I have a certificate for it in ACM.

My template is currently as follows:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.
Resources:
  ExampleWebApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: Example.WebApi::Example.WebApi.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync
      Runtime: dotnetcore2.1
      CodeUri: ''
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 10
      Role: null
      Policies:
      - AWSLambdaFullAccess
      Environment:
        Variables: {}
      Events:
        PutResource:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: "/{proxy+}"
            Method: ANY
```

Comment: How are you calling your Lambda function. I don't see the relevance of a domain name if you are calling the Labda via the AWS API... Only relevant if you are using API Gateway, in which case you are already using APIG, so custom domain name can be added to the APIG.

Comment: I'd like to call it directly from a mobile app, which I can already do via the api gateway that is created. However if I delete the stack and recreate it for any reason the url changes which is why I'd like to put my own domain in front of it which won't change. I'm aware that I can go into the console and manually add my domain to the gateway but I am unsure how to do it in the template

Comment: Does this help?: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/issues/40#issuecomment-411316776

Comment: Got it sorted now, that helped me a lot thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to use API Gateway in order to define a custom domain for a lambda function.